# Is it possible to scan local drive folder for SPAM Mails?

Tags: email, postfix, spam

I want to check a postfix mailbox folder directly on the Server. The server OS is Debian.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The canonical spam filter, SpamAssassin can scan both the Maildir (a format where each file in the directory contains only one message) or mbox (a single file containing one/more/all messages) mail store on your server.

See https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/spamassassin-run.html

```
spamassassin --mbox /var/spool/mail/hermanB
```

or

```
spamassassin /home/hermanB/Maildir/cur/
```

Running SpamAssassin as a daemon usually has better performance. Then you would use [spamc](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/spamc.html) to scan your messages.